# How println some data into browser console in scala play framework 2.4._?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

I've tried methods from this page https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaComet
but it didn't work.

I want println Json value.

Maybe I should something change in configurations?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "printing data into browser"?
Why would you need `comet` anyway?

Comment: If you want the output to appear in the browser's console, you would need to use the javascript console.log function.